# How to eval actionscript3's code in js or lua?

Tags: actionscript-3, lua

I'm writing a lua script. For some reason, I have to reuse some code written in as3.

The function in as3 is really long and obfuscated. It's time consuming to read and understand the as3 code and rewrite the some logic in lua.

Is there anyway I can evaluate the as3 souce code string in lua, so that I don't need to rewrite the same thing again?

Comment: You can invoke some external AS3 interpreter by `io.popen` and receive result printed to stdout.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Thanks a lot for mentioning AS3 interpreter, now I know where to dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Egor, After some digging, I found the solution to my problem: [redtamarin](http://redtamarin.com/about/description)

redtamarin is a runtime for as3 just as nodejs to javascript. It allows to run as3 code on the server side without flash player.